# Call to a method stored in a variable in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In an Angular 2 app, I'm trying to store a method in a variable but calling it always throws an error. I'll explain it better below:

I have to call to 3 different API methods for updating the database, depending on the user's type: customer, collaborator or provider. This is what I have right now:

```
let updateAPIMethod;

switch (user.type) {
    case OBJTYPES.CUSTOMER:
        updateAPIMethod = this.customerService.updateCustomer;
        break;
    case OBJTYPES.COLLAB:
        updateAPIMethod = this.collaboratorService.updateCollaborator;
        break;
    case OBJTYPES.PROVIDER:
        updateAPIMethod = this.providerService.updateProvider;
        break;
}
updateAPIMethod(user).subscribe( (ret) => { DEAL WITH SUCCESS },
    (error) => { DEAL WITH ERROR });
```

Each function is a call to http.put that return an Observable. When I run the above code I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'http' of undefined
```

I think it's because just calling the function doesn't set the appropiate 'this' value but I'm not sure...

Is there a way to do what I want? Thanks!

Comment: Did you really intend to `invoke` the function on this line?: `... = this.collaboratorService.updateCollaborator();`

Comment: have u imported http module from @angular/http in wherever your using http service

Comment: You're probable missing a `.bind(...)` or `=>` which breaks `bind`, but I don't see relevant code in your question where you pass the function to make more concrete suggestions how to fix.

Comment: First `updateAPIMethod = this.collaboratorService.updateCollaborator();`: are you shure aboit the call at the end? Secound: try to bind the correct `this` object by: `this.customerService.updateCustomer.bind(this.customerService)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You loose context when you detach method from base object. As a result `this.http` in your services is `undefined`.

This should work:

```
let updateAPIMethod;

switch (user.type) {
    case OBJTYPES.CUSTOMER:
        updateAPIMethod = this.customerService.updateCustomer.bind(this.customerService);
        break;
    case OBJTYPES.COLLAB:
        updateAPIMethod = this.collaboratorService.updateCollaborator.bind(this.collaboratorService);
        break;
    case OBJTYPES.PROVIDER:
        updateAPIMethod = this.providerService.updateProvider.bind(this.providerService);
        break;
}
updateAPIMethod(user).subscribe( (ret) => { DEAL WITH SUCCESS },
    (error) => { DEAL WITH ERROR });
```

You could also shorten it with [bind operator](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-function-bind/) (might need `transform-function-bind` babel plugin):

```
switch (user.type) {
    case OBJTYPES.CUSTOMER:
        updateAPIMethod = ::this.customerService.updateCustomer;
        break;
// ...
```